# Input multiple lines in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I get an error when I try to input for program that tries to find the
 location of a number in an array, I want to give the entire input at
 one go how can I do it, is there an easier way? Thank you. I get the
 following error when trying to execute in console in pycharm

Example

**Input**

2
4
1 2 3 4
3
5
10 90 20 30 40
40

```
 # Returns index of x in arr if it is present,
 # else returns -1
 def search(arr, x):
     n = len(arr)
     for j in range(0,n):
         if (x == arr[j]):
             return j
     return -1

 # Input number of test cases
 t = int(raw_input())

 # One by one run for all input test cases
 for i in range(0,t):

     # Input the size of the array
     n = int(raw_input())

     # Input the array
     arr = map(int, raw_input().split())

     # Input the element to be searched
     x = int(raw_input())

     print(search(arr, x))
```

> On pycharm console my input:

```
2  
4
1 2 3 4  
3  
5  
10 90 20 30 40  
40
```

**Output**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):  
 File "<input>", line 8, in <module>  
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2\n 41 2 3 4\n 3\n 5\n 10 90 >20 30 40\n 40'
```

Answer (score 0):

Bcoz the input string can not convert to int ('2\n 41 2 3 4\n 3\n 5\n 10 90 >20 30 40\n 40')
You should parse the input value with '\n' and ' ' fist and then convert to int numbers

Comment: There has to be another way where we can just input the values instead of parsing them in pycharm. How would one tackle this in competitive programs